# Count duplicates in a row in excel

Tags: excel

The sheet i made is for partners for different quarters, so i have person's name, and then 3 columns with random buttons to paste. That all works fine.

All i want to do is look at the row to see if there is a name there more than once, and then count it

For example

if the results are

```
Q1:A
Q2:A
Q3:B
Q4:B
```

Count would be: `2`

Another example

```
Q1: A
Q2: B
Q3: B
Q4: B
```

Count would be: `3`

I don't need to know how many of each one, but one number of all duplicates

Comment: I don't understand the logic. How come the first one isn't `4` (or vice versa, why isn't the second example `2`)? Can you give more examples. Perhaps that will help clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

**Get the letter:** `=MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND(":",A2))`

**Count how many times appears in the range:**`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,"=" & B2)`

**Get the maximum:**`=MAX(C2:C5)`

[image]

Comment: You can skip the middle step with an array verison of MAX(COUNTIF()): `=MAX(COUNTIF(B2:B5,B2:B5))`

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for clarification, but i try to keep it as simple i can in order to understand if the was the case because the questions is not clear enough.

Comment: I realize that, my comment was more to the OP.

Comment: Hey, i actually figured it out, came back here to delete this post